# Modal dialog z-index

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, z-index

My Bootstrap modal dialog is showing underneath a full screen background image for the page. My CSS class for this background image is:

```
.fullscreen_bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url('http://cleancanvas.herokuapp.com/img/backgrounds/color-splash.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

My Bootstrap modal dialog and fullscreen background image together looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="fullscreen_bg" class="fullscreen_bg"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="error_modal" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="error_modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login error</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I tried changing the `z-index` for the dialog and background image with no success. The `z-index` of modal dialog seems to be set at 1040 by default. I thought this was high enough to make it appear right at the top. So, how can I make the bootstrap dialog appear on the top-most layer of the page?

Comment: Can you post the entire code

Comment: Did you try to put `z-index: 1;` on your background image class?

Comment: should you use that .fullscreen_bg class somewhere in that code?

Comment: Updated to show full code

Comment: Just tried with `z-index: 1;` on background, no success. The z-index of the modal is 1040, this is what I can see in the element inspection.

Comment: Futher more, i might be wrong but shouldn't you have that div with fullscreen_bg inside modal class div? Triggering modal opens up <div class="modal"> not its parent.